# My shell script for checking leap year is showing error

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the year (YYYY)"
read year

if[ $((year % 4)) -eq 0] 
then
  if[ $((year % 100)) -eq 0] 
    then
    if[ $((year % 400)) -eq 0] 
          then 
        echo "its a leap year"
    else
           echo "its not a leap year"
    fi
  else
  echo "Its not a leap year"
  fi
else
 echo "its not a leap year"

fi
```

its showing error on 7th line and also on

```
[ $((year % 4)) -eq 0]
```

Comment: And the error message is?

Comment: 'Cool story bro'. Please provide detail on the error you are receiving and what steps you have taken to try and solve it - we might then be able to help :)

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Simpler: `date -d "$year-02-29" >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "It's a leap year" || echo "It's not a leap year"`

Answer (score 12):

You've made it too complicated. Use this code to figure leap year:

```
isleap() { 
   year=$1
   (( !(year % 4) && ( year % 100 || !(year % 400) ) )) &&
      echo "leap year" || echo "not a leap"
}
```

**Test it:**

```
$ isleap 1900
not a leap
$ isleap 2000
leap year
$ isleap 2016
leap year
$ isleap 1800
not a leap
$ isleap 1600
leap year
```

Comment: How to save the "leap year" into a variable instead of echoing it?

Comment: @SantosaSandy `res=$(isleap 2000)`

Answer (score 3):

You miss some blanks which are nesessary in bash:

```
echo "Enter the year (YYYY)"
read year

if [ $((year % 4)) -eq 0 ]
then
  if [ $((year % 100)) -eq 0 ]
    then
    if [ $((year % 400)) -eq 0 ]
          then
        echo "its a leap year"
    else
           echo "its not a leap year"
    fi
  else
  echo "Its a leap year"
  fi
else
 echo "its not a leap year"

fi
```

Comment: This logic is not working, as per http://www.onlineconversion.com/leapyear.htm 2016 is a leap year, but this script output showing as NOT a leap year.

Comment: @smc  In the original code, as well as this code, the third echo should say that it **is** a leap year (years divisible by 4 but not by 100 are leap years).  As written, it only identifies leap centuries as leap years.

Answer (score 0):

Test This Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter a year to check - "

read y

year=$y 

ans=`expr $year % 4`

if [ $ans -eq 0 ]

then    

    echo "Leap Year"

else

    echo "Not a Leap Year"

fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I like one-liners because I do a lot of scripting.  Here's an awk solution and test code:

#!/bin/csh  -f

set years = "1898 1899 1900 1901 1902 1903 1904 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2016"

foreach year ($years)
echo -n "$year "
echo $year | awk '{if(($1%4)!=0){ly=0}else{if(($1%400)==0){ly=1}else{if(($1%100)==0){ly=0}else{ly=1}}}} END{if(ly){print "yes"}else{print "no"}}'
end

The logic is elsewhere on this page

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also

```
if [[ $(( y % 4 )) = 0 && $(( y % 400 )) = 0 || $(( y % 100)) != 0 ]]
```

or

[image: Leap year]

Answer (score 0):

#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the year (YYYY)"

read year

if [ $((year%4)) -eq 0 ]

then

if [ $((year%100)) -eq 0 ]

```
then

if [ $((year%400)) -eq 0 ]

      then

    echo "its a leap year"

else

       echo "its not a leap year"

fi
```

else

echo "Its a leap year"

fi

else

echo "its not a leap year"

fi

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If your shell supports -d argument, try this out....

If yyyy0229 exists it will return date and return code 0 else it will throw error and return code 1.

```
    year=$(date +"%Y")
    echo "current year: ${year}"
    leapyear=$(date -d "${year}0229")
    if [ ${leapyear} = 0 ]
    then
        echo "Leap year"
    else
        echo "not a Leap year"
    fi
```