# Syntax error in Python 3.7: in line "if (year % 4) and (year % 100) and (year % 400):"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following program to find out the leap year

```
year = int(input("Enter a year: ")
if (year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 == 0) and (year % 400 == 0):
    print("True")
else: 
    print("False")
```

However, I'm getting following syntax error

```
File "is_leap.py", line 2
if (year % 4) and (year % 100) and (year % 400):
                                               ^
```

I do not understand why it is showing syntax error in **:**

P.S: I am newbie to Python and programming, and I knew there are solutions in online to figure out leap year. But I'm trying to figure this in my way.

I'm trying to understand why it's showing this syntax error while the "if" condition should have : in Python.

Comment: missing parenthesis `int(input("Enter a year: ")`

Comment: Oops, thanks @Rakesh

Comment: apart from the syntax error, you also have a logic error. That's not a correct way to check for leap years. You're basically return true only if year % 400 = 0

Comment: @phuclv yes, and I'm getting incorrect output. If I'm not wrong, if the output of ( year % 4), (year % 100) and (year % 400) returns 0, then it is a leap year. Am I correct? as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/32196765/9403545 ?

Comment: The correct computation is `(year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 != 0) or (year % 400 == 0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line itself is fine.

You're missing a closing parenthesis on the line before it:

```
year = int(input("Enter a year: ")
                                  ^^^^
```

P. S. Not directly related to your question, but to make the leap calculation work you'll need to invert some of the conditions in that `if` statement -- I'll let you figure out the details yourself.